# How does a va_list from an ellipses interact with a vfprintf() call?

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

I'm working on patching some old code (15-20 year old) and I come across strange segments from time to time.  Here is one that has me scratching my head.

```
27  void FormDefFileScanner::FormDefFileerror(char *fmt, ...)
28  {
29  va_list va;
30  va_start(va, fmt);
31  /* This is related to some sort of debuging */
32  if (FormDefFilelineno)
33      fprintf(stderr, "%d: ", FormDefFilelineno);
34  /* This is where I'm unsure */
35  (void) vfprintf(stderr, fmt, va);
36  fputc('\n', stderr);
37  va_end(va);
... /* rest of the program */
... }
```

I know from my research on the "..." argument how va_list is supposed to work.  By that I mean a va_arg() call with the list and variable type are required to pull values correctly from va_list.  I guess I'm wondering how a vprintf() call can correctly parse a va_list.  I assume the format string helps, but I'm not sure that every thing in va_list has the same word size.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything in the `va_list` definitely does _not_ have the same word size.

Comment: Why wouldn't `vfprintf` be able to parse it? `vfprintf` is a function explicitly defined for this specific task.

Comment: @LB--: I interpret this as how do `va_arg` and `vfprintf` work?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. If  `vfprintf` is expecting an array, arrays inherently contain variables of a uniform type. I was having a difficult time assuming that `vfprintf` was smart enough to parse through a body of memory that had values with different word size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets play "Imagination".   Imagine this code:

```
typedef char* va_list;
#define va_start(va_bytes, arg) (va_bytes=reinterpret_cast<char*>((&arg)+1))
#define va_end(va_bytes)
#define va_arg(va_bytes,type) (*reinterpret_cast<type*>((va_bytes+=sizeof(type))-sizeof(type)))
```

So your code becomes this:

```
void FormDefFileScanner::FormDefFileerror(char *fmt, ...)
{
    char* va_bytes;
    va_bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>((&fmt)+1); //points at first byte of ...
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, va_bytes); //passes a pointer to the bytes to vfprintf.
```

Then vprintf can do this:

```
void vfprintf(FILE*, char* format, char* va_bytes)
{
    if (strcmp(format,"%d")==0) { //now we know the first param is an int
        //I'm splitting the macro into two lines here for clarity
        int value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(va_bytes);
        va_bytes += sizeof(int); //va_bytes now points at the second parameter

    } else if (strcmp(format,"%llu")==0) { //first param is an long long unsigned int
        //I'm splitting the macro into two lines here for clarity
        long long unsigned value = *reinterpret_cast<long long unsigned*>(va_bytes);
        va_bytes += sizeof(long long unsigned); //va_bytes now points at the second parameter
    }
```

At all times, va_bytes points at the start of the next parameter.  When given a `va_arg`, it converts those bytes to that type, and advances the pointer to just after that, which is the start of the *subsequent* parameter.  It can't advance until you tell it the type via `va_arg`, because it doesn't know the types, and thus it doesn't know how many bytes are in each argument.

The real `va_arg` macro is far more complicated, because it deals with type alignments and such, and `vfprintf` *clearly* works nothing like I coded, but these should help clarify the general concepts.

Comment: I'm glad for the conceptual overview; I'm glad that the way I thought it worked is the way you think it works.  Thank you!

Comment: "The real `va_arg` macro is far more complicated, because it deals with type promotions and such," -- It doesn't have to. If the caller passed a `short`, which gets promoted to `int`, then the variadic function must use `va_arg(ap, int)`. The definition of `va_arg` does not have to cover a user writing `va_arg(ap, short)`, because the behaviour of that is simply undefined, and typical definitions of `va_arg` really don't handle that. But you are right that `va_arg` is a bit more complicated: one important issue is alignment, so `va_bytes` might need to be incremented more than `sizeof(type)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I'm wondering how a `vprintf()` call can correctly parse a
>   `va_list`. I assume the format string helps, but I'm not sure that every
>   thing in `va_list` has the same word size.

Things in a `va_list` do *not* have the same size. `vprintf` wouldn't have to "parse a `va_list`" manually -- it can just use `va_arg`. It knows what type the next argument needs to be, because of the format specifier in the format string. So you can imagine that if you were to write `vprintf`, inside the loop that parses the format string, you would have cases for each format specifier, and then in each case they would use `va_arg` to get the next argument of the correct type:

```
if (strcmp(format,"%d")==0) {
    int value = va_arg(va, int);
    // do stuff ...

} else if (strcmp(format,"%f")==0) {
    double value = va_arg(va, double);
    // do stuff ...
}
//...
```

As for how `va_list`, `va_arg`, etc. are implemented, that is something that is opaque and you shouldn't care about, because it varies depending on architecture and system. You just need to know that if you follow the contract of `va_start`, `va_arg`, etc., it works.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this.  I guess it's just surprising to me that `vprintf()` would accept `va_list` and know what to do with it.  I always thought `vprintf()` assumed the last argument would be an array, which would lead to the further assumption that the array would have a constant word size throughout, being it's not a struct.  Since both answers to my question say this, and the 20 year old code is functioning all over the world, I'm inclined to believe you.  I'm still just surprised at the foresight of whoever wrote `vprintf()`.